# Align field names to right using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I use iTextSharp to generate pdf & after generate pdf I want to display text in following format

```
   First Name : sandip
      Company : ABC
Mobile Number : 2222222222
```

My code is

```
var MName = new Phrase();
MName.Add(new Chunk("Name:  ", boldFont));//Merchant Name      
MName.Add(new Chunk(MfirstName + " " + MLastName, normalFont));
merinfotbl.AddCell(MName);
```

I want the following output (the field names are aligned to right)

```
        First Name : sandip
           Company : ABC
     Mobile Number : 2222222222
```

but it gives the following output instead (the field names are aligned to left)

```
        First Name : sandip
        Company : ABC
        Mobile Number : 2222222222
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: That is easy to do using a two or three column table.

Comment: no dear i want this in single column.

Comment: You can put another table into that single cell.

Comment: @mkl Right! One single table of two columns working inside the pdfDoc as  a cell is the solution

Comment: I'll make it an actual answer.

Comment: i add another table in column & it's working .Thanx #mkl

Answer (score 0):

A structure as described by the OP can easily be created using a table with two or three columns (depending on whether one wants to put the colons into a column of their own or not) using right aligned content in the first column and left aligned content in the last one.

Even if the structure already is the content of a cell of a larger table, one can still put a small table into a cell of a large table.

Beware, though: In general I would advice against overdoing it, tables with many other tables in their cells which may in turn contain yet other tables might make layout'ing very slow. Used cautiously, though, tables in cells of other tables can simplify one's code considerably.